# Is there an odd word in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Invented in 1440 by the German scientist and engineer Johannes 
>   Gutenberg, the printing press is one of the finest inventions.

Is there an odd word in this sentence? Is the definite article in "the German scientist" correct?

Comment: I think the odd word is "is". In normal speech I think most people would use "was". The invention was in the past, and that printing press has nothing in common with any kind of printing press currently in use.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is correct, but I can see why it might look odd. The definite article is used because "scientist" and "engineer" both refer to one specific person, Johannes Gutenberg. Consider the simpler sentence:

> The scientist Johannes Gutenberg invented the printing press.

In both your example and the simpler alternative, "the scientist" refers to one specific person, so the definite article is appropriate. In the complicated original sentence, "the" applies to both "scientist" and "engineer".

---

However, the sentence could also be written *without* the definite article:

> Scientist Johannes Gutenberg invented the printing press.

In this alternative, "scientist" is being used in a slightly different way. In this case, the word acts as a role or title, which are often used without definite articles.

As another alternative, the indefinite article could be used:

> A scientist named Johannes Gutenberg invented the printing press.

With the *indefinite* article, the emphasized meaning is "a scientist invented the printing press" with added information that the name of this scientist was Johannes Gutenberg. The original version with the *definite* article emphasizes "Johannes Gutenberg invented the printing press" and specifies that he is a scientist and engineer. Since he is a famous historical person, he is known as "*the* scientist and engineer Johannes Gutenberg".

---

Sentences in English can often be written using the definite article, the indefinite article, or no article at all, with all three choices being grammatically correct. However, each choice is appropriate only for a certain context. Someone *creating* the sentence (either in speech or writing) must make the choice based on their intended meaning, but a person hearing or reading the sentence can only *infer* the intended meaning based on the article choice. If the sentence is created with an inappropriate article, then the listener or reader may understand a different meaning than was intended without being aware of the mistake, because the sentence can still be grammatical.